# Catching 401 and refreshing Firebase Id Token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, httpclient, retrofit2

My app uses Firebase to authenticate users by phone number, a migration from Digits.
I add the idToken from Firebase to my calls.
I listen with an interceptor on my httpclient if a 401 was trown, if so, I logged out.

I noticed after one hour the 401 came in, so I added an addIdTokenListener in my App class. When it changes I update my token to sign my calls.
It worked, but not flawless, sometimes a 401 was thrown and I still logged the user out...

I am writing something in my interceptor to get the IdToken from the user, but the call firebaseUser.getIdToken() is async. So I'm starting to make things complicated, I guess.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? What is your workflow?

Answer (score 2):

You're going in the right direction. One thing you may want to do is alter your logic a little based on the reason for the ID token validation failure. You can [unpack the ID token data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) yourself and check the expiration field. If the token has expired, return a different code that triggers the retrieval process, before trying the call again.